# Showing my php echo on android device

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-studio

I would like to show my php echo when username or email already exist in my database

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email'";

    $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

        if(isset($check)){
            echo "username or email already exist";
        }else {

            $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO User (username, email, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $username, $email, $age, $password);
        }

mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);
```

It doesn't create the account when the email or username already exist but it doesn't show my echo and exit my registration activity.

Here is my ServerRequests.java

```
 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", user.email));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", user.age + ""));

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = getHttpRequestParams();

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS
                + "Register.php");


        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            client.execute(post);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    private HttpParams getHttpRequestParams() {
        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        return httpRequestParams;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        userCallBack.done(null);
    }
```

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 0):

echo method used on PHP for a print
if you want to send message to your app
just use variable as $msg instead of echo
and request $msg in your app

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email'";

    $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

        if(isset($check)){
            $msg = "username or email already exist";
        }else {

            $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO User (username, email, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $username, $email, $age, $password);
            $msg = "Created";
        }
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: yes and how can I request it ? checked everywhere but always differents answers